# How do I convert this javascript to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to learn TS and I think I got the basics, but I realy could need som help converting my first .js file to .ts (latest). What's the best pattern to use in .ts when using the following pattern in .js (an example would be greatly appreciated).

My .js file:

```
var BokaHanterareIndex = {
  config: {
    showBtn: "#show",
    weekPicker: "#pickWeek",
  },

  init: function (config) {
    // provide for custom configuration via init()
    if (config && typeof (config) == 'object') {
      $.extend(BokaHanterareIndex.config, config);
    }

// Cache DOM objects
BokaHanterareIndex.$showBtn = $(BokaHanterareIndex.config.showBtn);
BokaHanterareIndex.$weekPicker = $(BokaHanterareIndex.config.weekPicker);

//Init 
BokaHanterareIndex.$weekPicker.datepicker({
  language: "sv",
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true,
  todayBtn: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});

//event
BokaHanterareIndex.$showBtn.click(function () {
  BokaHanterareIndex.$weekPicker.datepicker('show');
});
 },
    showHours: function (message) {
    alert(message);
  },
}
```

And on my html fil i just call it like this:

```
BokaHanterareIndex.init({showBtn: "#showButton"});
```

(sometimes I need to override the default values in config)

So far I have tried this:

```
interface IBokaHanterareIndexConfig {
  showBtn?: string;
  weekPicker?: string;
}

class BokaHanterareIndexTest {
  private $showBtn: JQuery;
  private $weekPicker: JQuery;

  private config: IBokaHanterareIndexConfig = {
    showBtn: "#show",
    weekPicker: "#pickWeek"
  }

  init(config: IBokaHanterareIndexConfig) {
    $.extend(this.config, config);

    this.$showBtn = $(this.config.showBtn);
    this.$weekPicker = $(this.config.weekPicker);

    //Koppla event
    this.$showBtn.click(() => {
      this.$weekPicker.datepicker('show');
    });
  }

  showHours(message : string): void {
    alert(message);
  }
}
```

But when I try to initialize it like this:

```
var test = new BokaHanterareIndexTest();
test.init({ showBtnn: "#test" });
```

the showBtnn is not beeing marked as an error, eventhough it's not spelled right. (I'm using VS 2013)

Regards
Per

Comment: Typescript is a superset of javascript. That means pretty much most code that's valid javascript is also valid typescript. Looking at your code you just need to change the file extension.

Comment: You have to try something, there are way too many different valid ways to do this. If you explain what you're having difficulty with, wrt can help

Comment: Updated my post and added what I tried so far

Comment: enclose `showBtnn` in quoatation marks

Comment: Still not getting an error when it compiles the .ts :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `class`. Something along these lines:

```
class BokaHanterareIndex {
    config: Object = {showBtn: "#show",weekPicker: "#pickWeek"};

    init(config: Object) {
          //Type check not needed as we force an Object to be passed in.
          $.extend(BokaHanterareIndex.config, config);

      ... 
    }
}
```

In this case, you would initialize it like so:

```
let xyz = new BokaHanterereIndex();
xyz.init({showBtn: "#showButton"});
```

**OR**

You could replace `init` with `constructor` and have a smaller initialization, like so:

```
let xyz = new BokaHanterereIndex({"showBtn": "#showButton"});
```

There's documentation on TypeScript classes available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Converting `BokuHanterareIndex` and its anonymous objects to classes you get something like this:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery.d.ts" />

export class BokaHanterareConfig {
    constructor(public showBtn: string,
                public weekPicker: string) {
    }
}

export class DatePickerConfig {
    constructor(public language: string,
                public calendarWeeks: boolean,
                public autoclose: boolean,
                public todayBtn: boolean,
                public todayHighlight: boolean) {
    }
}

export class BokaHanterareIndex {
    private config: BokaHanterareConfig = new BokaHanterareConfig("#show", "#pickWeek");

    $showBtn: JQuery;
    $weekPicker: JQuery | any;

    constructor() {
    }

    init(config?: any): void {
        if (config && typeof (config) == 'object') {
            $.extend(this.config, config);
        }

        // Cache DOM objects
        this.$showBtn = $(this.config.showBtn);
        this.$weekPicker = $(this.config.weekPicker);

        //Init 
        this.$weekPicker.datepicker(new DatePickerConfig("sv", true, true, true, true));

        //event
        this.$showBtn.click(() => {
            this.$weekPicker.datepicker('show');
        })
    }

    showHours(message: string): void {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this in your code:

```
import { BokaHanterareIndex } from 'bokuhanterareindex';

let bokaHanterareIndex: BokaHanterareIndex = new BokaHanterareIndex();
bokaHanterareIndex.init();
```